# Parso Java Library Issue

Tags: java, sas

I am trying to use the Parso Java Library in order to read in a .sas7bdat file. My goal is to convert it to a CSV, and then manipulate it further afterwards. Directions I am following for setting it up are [here.](http://scitouch.net/opensource/parso) I have the parso .jar file imported into Eclipse successfully. However, when I try to instantiate as so:

```
    InputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(sasFile);
    SasFileReader sasFileReader = new SasFileReader(streamIn);
```

I get this exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main"    
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at com.ggasoftware.parso.SasFileReader.<clinit>(SasFileReader.java:30)
at sas7bdatFileConverter.convert(sas7bdatFileConverter.java:25)
at sas7bdatFileConverter.main(sas7bdatFileConverter.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I would greatly appreciate any hints as to what I might be missing here. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the Maven dependency, or are you directly importing the .jar? In the former case, it would work. For the latter, you also need to include a slf4j jar file (and that's either slf4j-api which doesn't actually do anything, or at least slf4j-simple which logs to the console).

Comment: You need slf4j on your class path at runtime.

Comment: You were both right, thank you! I don't have 15 rep yet so no upvote... I appreciate it regardless.

Answer (score 2):

The page you cited says you should be using a Maven dependency (which will automatically download all the jar files needed), but it seems like you are directly importing the jar file.

Because you're not using Maven, you also need to include a slf4j jar file (and that's either slf4j-api which doesn't actually do anything, or at least slf4j-simple which logs to the console).

Simply go to http://www.slf4j.org/ and download the newest package, then take out `slf4j-api-<version>.jar` (and `slf4j-simple-<version>.jar` if you want to see the Parso library logging into your console).

In the long run, definitely learn how to use Maven, it will immensely ease your pain with library management.